# How do I send a javascript value to a PHP page, then reference that value IN the PHP page?

Tags: php, ajax

How do I send a javascript value to a PHP page, then reference that value IN the PHP page?

Assuming I have some sort of javascript AJAX solution such as this:

```
var id=5;
      obj.onreadystatechange=showContent;
      obj.open("GET","test.php",true);
      obj.send(id);
```

I want to work with this particular id in the test.php. How can I do this?

Comment: javascript code....i want to work with id

Comment: Never, ever name a variable `obj`.  The very fact that anybody looking at this code would immediately ask "what is `obj`?" tells you that your code isn't expressing intent.

Comment: @jcolebrand will you suggest me a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the javascript (I'm making a function so you can assign it to some other event)

```
//jQuery has to be included, and so if it's not, 
//I'm going to load it for you from the CDN, 
//but you should load this by default in your page using a script tag, like this:
//<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')

function sendValueGet(passedValue){
  jQuery.get('test.php', { value: passedValue });
}
function sendValuePost(passedValue){
  jQuery.post('test.php', { value: passedValue });
}
```

And then in your PHP:

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["value"] )
{
   $value = $_REQUEST['value'];
   echo "Received ". $value;
}
?>
```

Notice that I use "value" in the javascript "object" `{ value: ... }` and in the PHP "REQUEST" variable `$_REQUEST["value"]`

If you want to give that a different reference name, then you need to change it in both places.

Using GET or POST is your preference.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
obj.open("GET","test.php?id=" + id,true);
obj.send();
```

Then in test.php use `$_GET['id']`

Comment: yeah, well not everyone learns native English when they are born

Comment: what if the request method is post

Comment: I'm not sure but I assume it would be something like `obj.open("POST", "test.php", true);
var params = {'id': id};
obj.send(params);`

Comment: but the get method is not so secure...??

Comment: GET method's parameters are visible in the URL

Comment: var params = {'id': id}; this is not working....i asked that how to get that id in the test.php..@slash197

Answer (score 1):

//GET

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    var x=xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert(x);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

in test.php

```
$id=$_GET['q']
```

//POST

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    var x=xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert(x);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);
xmlhttp.send("x=id");
```

in test.php

```
$id=$_POST['x']
```

Comment: He asked how can `id` be accessed in test.php, you didn't explain that

Comment: try this  xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("x=id");